# Json.reads on abstract class (Sealed trait is not supported: no known subclasses)

Tags: scala, implicit, play-json

I have an abstract class and object

```
sealed abstract class Granularity() {
  // some values and methods
}

object Granularity {
  final private case class WeekGranularity(name: String, windowSize: Int) extends Granularity("week", "'7' day") {
     // overriding methods
  }

  val Week: Granularity = WeekGranularity(name = "week", windowSize = 1)
}
```

I am using it in some other class like this

```
case class Meta(granularity: Granularity)

object Meta {
  implicit val granularityWrites = Writes[Granularity](d => JsString(d.toString))
  implicit val metaWrites = Json.writes[Meta]
}
```

Now when writing a spec like this, I get an error

```
class ControllerSpec {

  "MetaController" should {
      "return" {
         .
         .
         .
         // play 2.13 resp
         resp.body[JsValue].asOpt[Meta] should beSome(expectedMeta)
         // ERROR: No Json deserializer found for type models.Meta. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type
       }
  }
}
```

When I add an implicit Read on top inside Spec class, I still get an error

```
  implicit val granularityReads = Json.reads[Granularity] // ERROR: Sealed trait Granularity is not supported: no known subclasses
  implicit val metaReads = Json.reads[Meta]
```

I can do this to compare json, which works and I don't have to create any implicit.

```
resp.body[JsValue] shouldEqual Json.toJson(metricSignTimeseries)
```

But I want to understand how can I implement an implicit Read on Granularity?

Comment: Do you have a reason not to define a `Reads` for `WeekGranularity`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to read a `Granularity` from JSON data the library must be able to create an instance of `Granularity` in order to return it. But `Granularity` is an `abstract class` and you can't create instances of an abstract class.

`Json.reads` needs to be parameterised with a concrete class that can be instanciated by the library, or you need to write a custom `Reads[Granularity]` that creates and returns an appropriate subclass of `Granularity`.

I suggest that you don't put functionality in the classes that you use to read/write JSON or use complex class hierarchies. Just read the data into simple `case class` instances that directly match the JSON format, and then process them into application classes. This allows the storage formats and the internal application data formats to change independently rather than being tightly linked.